# In the square $ABCD$, prove that $BF+DE=AE$.

Tags: calculus, geometry, area

Consider the Square $ABCD$. The point $E$ is on the side $CD$. If $F$ is on the side $BC$ such that $AF$ is the bisector of the angle $BAE$. Prove that
$$BF+DE=AE.$$
By Pythagorean theorem we have $(AD)^2+(DE)^2=(AE)^2$ then $DE=\sqrt{(AE)^2-(AD)^2}$ also, $DE=AE\sin(EAD)$ and $BF=AF\sin(BAF)$ on the other hand we have $BAE+EAD=90^0$

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Théophile, prove the mentioned identity is my question.

Comment: Well, it's not written as a question, it's more of an order. Have you done any work on this yourself?

Comment: Yes I drew the shape and use some properties of bisectors also Applying Pythagorean theorem, but I did not reach to aim.

Comment: Good. Please add an explanation of your work so far to make it easier to answer your question.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** Rotate the $F$ around $A$ for $90^{\circ}$ (you get new point name it $H$) and $B$ goes to $D$. Note that $E,D,H$ are collinear. Now use congruence theorems. (Prove that $HE =EA$.)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Let $AB=x$ and angle $<BAF=<FAE=\alpha=> DE=x\tan(\frac{\pi}{2}-2\alpha),\; BF=x\tan\alpha=>$
$$
\\BF+DE=x(\tan(\frac{\pi}{2}-2\alpha)+\tan\alpha)=x(\cot2\alpha+\tan\alpha)
\\AE=\frac{x}{\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}-2\alpha)}=\frac{x}{\sin2\alpha}
\\BF+DE=AE<=>\cot2\alpha+\tan\alpha=\frac{1}{\sin2\alpha}<=>
\\\cos2\alpha=1-2\sin^2\alpha
$$